# TypeScript TupleIndexed type and enforce read only for arrays passed in as arguments

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create `type` in TypeScript that takes a type parameter `T` and tuple/ReadonlyArray of `keyof T` and returns a ReadonlyArray of the keys indexed into `T`.

```js
type TupleIndexed<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>> = {
  [C in keyof K]: T[C];
};
```

But I get `Type 'C' cannot be used to index type 'T'`.

One workaround I found is

```js
type TupleIndexed<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof any>> = {
  [C in keyof K]: K[C] extends keyof T ? T[K[C]] : never;
};
```

While it gets the job done, I don't understand why the conditional is necessary for the compiler.

This way I'm able to write typed functions that preserve the positional type information like the following

```js
function pluck<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(obj: T, keys: K): TupleIndexed<T, K> {
  return keys.map(key => obj[key]);
}

const vals = pluck({name: 'John', age: 25, adult: true}, [
  'name', 
  'age', 
  'adult'
] as const);
const name = vals[0]; // string
const age = vals[1]; // number
const adult = vals[2]; // boolean
const doesNotExist = vals[3]; // ERROR
```

However, even in this solution, not casting the array `as const` still compiles

```js
function pluck<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(obj: T, keys: K): TupleIndexed<T, K> {
  return keys.map(key => obj[key]);
}

const vals = pluck({name: 'John', age: 25, adult: true}, [
  'name', 
  'age', 
  'adult'
]);  // Not explicitly stating as const still compiles
const name = vals[0]; // string | number | boolean
const age = vals[1]; // string | number | boolean
const adult = vals[2]; // string | number | boolean
const doesNotExist = vals[3]; // string | number | boolean
```

Which loses all the positional type safety. Is there a way to automatically cast the array `as const` or otherwise have the compiler throw an error when it isn't casted `as const`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically cast the array as `const` or otherwise have the compiler throw an error when it isn't casted as `const`?

As far as I know, there is not.

However, using a rest parameter instead of an array will result in TypeScript treating it as a tuple instead of an array. Of course this also means have to call it slightly differently:

```js
type TupleIndexed<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof any>> = {
  [C in keyof K]: K[C] extends keyof T ? T[K[C]] : never;
};

function pluck<T, K extends ReadonlyArray<keyof T>>(obj: T, ...keys: K): TupleIndexed<T, K> {
//                                                          ^^^
  return keys.map(key => obj[key]) as any;
}

const vals = pluck({name: 'John', age: 25, adult: true}, 'name', 'age', 'adult');
const name = vals[0]; // string
const age = vals[1]; // number
const adult = vals[2]; // boolean
const doesNotExist = vals[3]; // error
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABxhA1gZSnATgUwGcAeAFQBpEBpRfADynzABNDEAKdfATzmEVIBKANoBdAHztccOFGx58ALgGUAdOq7dCyqoOUBvRMICSiGEk19qo5aWGX+pRADJqJ0aMQBfRPoBQiIGIBFAguBY8hKoAtgCGyOycPMoOAoKIALzivgFBeQD0+YjqqrmBXumIsWyxYNwA3H5efn5Q3Mj4AiDIADb4xiz0+MxklDT0jCxsAEr4scwIPdwAgri4sdzEqaTi2Rk5gcIAwmYRvPxUNgLCVMeertuijV6NfqCQsAgoPSAYo9S0BhMViIWbzRYrNYbLY8Kw7SRwABGACtbJRNNpqHour1+oM6MN-lRsv5AiEwmconEEppMtkkcj7DxROlqlU6s8WhAEIQoIgAG6xHpsfa9X7odj6MCxaJKRAAcgAUnAABZgeWUWIAczlACYAKya5ggHpQZRQXAgfBeSjCXLy6WyjWIe3a-DO13G03yvyeNncsC8wSvAO8xCOzr7QXC4QABieiEKiF5uHMWr8ob5bsyAqFhGEAEYE0mwCBooj8LgMzys16+VG88JdcWioiZH1atXA3yFkQAHKyACidBgYYbMYAzC3EIPptMAPLTIA)